# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined on Coupons-for-Gravity-Forms

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, gravity

I have a wordpress site.
I've installed a coupon plugin into my copy of gravity forms, it works fine on the forms preview page when I go to test it there, however, I cannot get the field to work on the frontend of the site. I get a ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined appearing.

Have tested that jquery has loaded correctly in the header tag and in the correct order. I have tried changing themes through the standard default themes. And tried redefining jQuery to something else.

The only plugin running on the site is better security, so there is nothing outside the default installation. Am running WP 3.4.2 and gravity forms 1.6.9 and Coupons-for-Gravity-Forms found on github.

My test site is http://monkfish-uk.com/critical/order-form/ there should be a button that says apply next to the coupon field on the second page of the form.

Am a bit stumped.

cheers

Will

On closer inspection, there is an iframe in the page where the error is actually being called, so I am guessing that jquery is not being loaded in the iframe, should this matter?